# Menus disappear on update to 5.20.2 (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, menu, resource-urls

- Wordpress 5.3.1 (on Siteground)
- [upgrading from CiviCRM 5.19.2 to] CiviCRM 5.20.1/2

Apart from a (quite lengthy) list of templates that might be affected by the db upgrade, this process goes as expected. But upon reloading, I lose the CiviCRM menus and get, instead, the weird mile-long mess at the bottom of the page.

I can confirm a 404 error on the crm-menubar css, and I can also see that the path to that file has changed from the previous installation. The previous path had been:

> www.mysite.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/crm-menubar.blahblah.css

in version 5.20.2, it is:

> www.mysite.org/home/user_directory/www/mysite.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/crm-menubar.blahblah.css

So I've changed the $civicrm_root (in the settings file) to:

> /home/user_directory/www/mysite.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

But I'm still getting the 404.

I have:

- double checked the directory permissions (though it isn't clear why these might have changed)
- cleaned up the caches and updated the paths
- read about a whole lot of similar cases, here

This isn't (yet) a crisis or anything, but I do keep reverting back to the previous version, as it's a lot pleasanter to deal with (though the security warnings are working as they should, and I'd really like to get this patch).

I suspect that this is related to resource URLs, but I'm not sure what additional steps to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of $civicrm_root was indeed the problem; in my settings.php (which had been working for a while) the path used Siteground username (as does DocumentRoot), whereas this should be replaced by the generic 'customer.'

How I got there:

It was obvious that something was wrong with the Resource URL, but I couldn't figure it out (as the comments should make clear). So I reverted to 5.19.2, made a full-site backup, and then uninstalled CiviCRM completely: plugins/civicrm, uploads/civicrm, and the db. Then ran a fresh install to autogenerate a new settings.php file, which I downloaded.

Then I restored the full-site backup & ran the CiviCRM update as normal, except that I put the newly-generated settings.php file in place before upgrading the db. This worked, fortunately, and the only difference between the settings files was the one described above.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure the directory path defined for $civicrm_root of your site matches with DocumentRoot mentioned in your apache2/nginx conf setting. They should match with each other.

The other option is to set 'CiviCRM Resource URL' in Resource url setting to http://www.mysite.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

Comment: DocumentRoot: /home/user_name/www/mysite.org/public_html

$civicrm_root: /home/user_name/www/mysite.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

So that looks OK, no?

The resource URL setting is read-only.

Comment: OK, adjusted the settings.php file so that I could change the resource URL -- set it as suggested here and then updated the paths. Same result (i.e., still showing a 404 error).

Comment: I'm thinking it may make sense to wipe out everything in plugins & uploads, install CiviCRM as a new plugin, and then restore the db. Would this work? Or is it pointless, as I can't really imagine the resource paths getting any clearer than they are? Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree, here.

Or I revert to 5.19, with the scary security warning? A bit lost . . .

Comment: For comparison, the menu .css that's not found (404): Request URL:https://mysite.org/home/user/www/mysite.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/crm-menubar.51fcaccee502d3f65ba2d9b8166e391b.css

VS


The rest of everything else, loading from the plugin directory: Request URL:https://mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css?r=VGCMB

Shouldn't these be the same paths, up to /plugins or /uploads?